# Assigning values in config file

Tags: scala, sbt, config

I am having an `application.conf` file in resources of an SBT project.

How can I assign variables inside this file?

For example:

```
project {
  fun1-version: "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  fun2-version: "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  fun3-version: "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  fun4-version: "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

}

So I do not want every time to change this `0.0.1` for each line. I have tried the following:

```
versions {
  ver1 : "0.0.1"
}

project {
  fun1-version: ${versions.ver1}"-SNAPSHOT"
  fun2-version: ${versions.ver1}"-SNAPSHOT"
  fun3-version: ${versions.ver1}"-SNAPSHOT"
  fun4-version: ${versions.ver1}"-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

But it does not seem that it is working. Any idea how can I do it?

Comment: Are you reading the configuration with com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory? The substitution should work in that case

Answer (score 0):

Your config file is correct.  You need to call `resolve()` on your config object after loading it.